# Time trigger in Google Script gives an error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to setup a time trigger for the google script to run on a schedule, but I get the following error. I'm trying to run a single script, which has 3 other scripts combined.

The script works fine when I manually run it.

Just to note, the date column in the sheet is populated using a formula and the date format is "m/dd/yyyy"

Error:

```
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
    at sendEmail(IntCode:54:32)
    at combine(Combine:6:3)
```

Line of Code (there are 3 of these, with few changes in row no., which I combine with "combine" script) - IntCode.gs

```
function getDataSheet() {

  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  numRows = 200;   // Number of rows to process
  startCol = 1;  //First column of data to process
  numCols = 21;    // Number of columns to process 
  
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols);

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();  

  return data;  
}

function sendFirstEmail() {
  var complete = "";
  var first = "Yes";
        
  var data = getDataSheet();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    
    var row = data[i];
    
    var isFirst = row[18];
    var isComplete = row[11];
    var user = row[0];
    var detail = row[1];
    var description = row[2];
    var period = row[3];
    var name_1 = row[4];
    var to_email_1 = row[5];
    var to_email_2 = row[6];
    var cc_email_1 = row[7];
    var cc_email_2 = row[8];
    var cc_email_3 = row[9];
    var email_1 = "email ID";
    var date = row[10];
                
    if(isFirst == first && isComplete == complete ) {
  

      var to_email_1 = row[5];
      var to_email_2 = row[6];
      var cc_email_1 = row[7];
      var cc_email_2 = row[8];
      var cc_email_3 = row[9];
      var email_1 = "email id";
      var period = row[3];
      var message = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FirstMail').getContent();
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(row[10], "GMT" , "dd/MMM/yyyy" );
      var file = row[12];
      
      message = message.replace("%user", user);
      message = message.replace("%detail", detail);
      message = message.replace("%description", description);
      message = message.replace("%period", period);
      message = message.replace("%name_1", name_1);
      message = message.replace("%date", date);
      message = message.replace("%file", file);
      
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      name: 'display name',
      to: to_email_1 + ", " + to_email_2,
      replyTo: email_1,
      cc: email_1 + ", " + cc_email_1 + ", " + cc_email_2 + ", " + cc_email_3,
      subject: "[TEST] " + detail + " on " + date,
      htmlBody: message
    });
      
      
    }
  }
}
```

The combine script (combine.gs) which I'm trying to setup with the time trigger.

```
function combine() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("google sheet ID");
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id_is_here/
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // name of the actual sheet ("Sheet 1" for example)  
  Logger.log('combine ran!');
  sendFirstEmail();
  sendSecondEmail();
  sendFinalEmail();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should share with us the lines of code that do not work . Even better, a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis, added now. Thanks. All these scripts run manually without any issue and I get the emails, without a problem. Only the time trigger gives the above error.

Comment: Try my answer to see if it works.

Comment: Don't forget to research and provide [mcve] on your new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message you are getting, it seems that `row[10]` is a string while it should be a **date** object.

Try to replace that line with the following:

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate( new Date(row[10]), "GMT" , "dd/MMM/yyyy" );
```

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20Date%20objects%20represent%20a,a%20new%20Date%2FTime%20API.) more about date objects.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I'm getting this error now. ```Exception: Invalid email: Internal
    at sendFirstEmail(IntCode:65:13)```

Comment: Now it looks like the emails you are providing are not correct. Try to Logger.log() all the email variables to be sure that they contain the expected value. For example try Logger.log(to_email_1) etc..

Comment: Then please accept the answer if I solved your question :)

Comment: Thank you. But the initial code I posted also worked without an issue manually, only thing it showed an error if Time Triggered. Still I have the same issue, but different error code when using your line of code. The issue I posted was that the time trigger is not working.

Comment: Like I said, try to Logger.log the email variables to see if they contain the proper information. If you don't want to share exactly the information, share the format. For example you can't send an email to : "12345". Therefore, check if all the variables you have contain the information you expect to contain and we go from there.

Comment: Thank you. Email format is correct (name.lastname@gmail.com) but I cannot share it here. Apologies. If there is a problem with the email format, would still the emails go when triggered manually?

Comment: Could you share with us the sendFirstEmail() function ?

Comment: @Spear Ask new questions for new errors. Follow up questions are preferable in a new post. The intent of the answerer is to solve the question posted not guide/tutor you until the end of your project or achieve  your goal.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis, I updated it in the above code in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @TheMaster, Thank you and noted. I was trying to find to navigate to make the trigger work. I wanted to fix it in the same question so that I do not create a new question with same info but different error code, but will do. Apologies for this.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be used as an email : `var email_1 = "email id";`

Comment: I have an email ID put in there in same format (name.lastname@gmail.com). Cannot be done like that?